# Bootstrap - Confidence Interval Calculation

Tags: python, python-3.x, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to implement bootstrap to estimate CI for statistics. Here is the code I have written

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
import pylab

def bootstrap(data, num_samples, statistic, alpha):
   """Returns bootstrap estimate of 100.0*(1-alpha) CI for statistic."""
    num_samples = len(data)
    idx = npr.randint(min(data), max(data), num_samples)
    samples = data[idx]
    stat = np.sort(statistic(samples, 1))
    return (stat[int((alpha/2.0)*num_samples)],
    stat[int((1-alpha/2.0)*num_samples)])

X,Y = np.loadtxt('data/ABC.txt',
                          unpack =True,
                          delimiter =',',
                          skiprows = 1)
```

The text file contains 2 columns and I need to calculate the confidence interval for both columns.
My first thought is to convert the columns into an array and calculate the high and low 95% CI. I was thinking of something like this:

```
data = np.array([X,Y])
low, high = bootstrap(X, len(data), np.mean, 0.05)
low1, high1 = bootstrap(Y, len(data), np.mean, 0.05)
```

But I am not sure if this the correct way of calculating confidence interval.  Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation first?

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: You can put print statements after each line with each variable content and see where and why things go wrong. Alternatively, you can use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pdb.html) or its ipython equivalent, [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) for an interactive debugging session.

Comment: you calculate confidence interval for a parameter using bootstrap. For example, we estimate the mean of the samples and calculate the 95% CI of the mean. what are you trying to measure here.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
idx = npr.randint(min(data), max(data), num_samples)
```

Use:

```
idx=np.random.choice(data,size=len(data),replace=True)
```